# iOS Push Notification for Enterprise In-house APP

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I have been following this article to the letter :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Everything works as described - right until the SimplePush test; I get this reply :

```
Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered
```

- which is fine - but nothing shows up on the iPhone.

Some facts :

- Using Enterprise Ad-hoc provisioning profile (with Push enabled)
- First start of app shows the expected : "APP" Would Like to Send You Push Notifications - Allow ? - Pop-up. Pressed "OK".
- Got the deviceToken - and using this in simplepush setting.
- ck.pem is stored same place as simplepush.php and passphrase set.
- Tested simplepush with all of the following : App open / App closed / App terminated

Anyone got ideas ?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: make sure you on production not on sandbox APNS

Comment: *doh* !!! - I didn't realize - this is exactly what solved it :-)
Thanks - been using almost 2 days recreating everything - certificates, prov. profiles - you name it ... Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make sure you on production not on sandbox APNS, is very frequent mistake